# Parsing json data in to Assemble 0.17.1 via Gulp

Tags: json, gulp, assemble

My Json data doesn´t get parsed.
Assemble v0.17.1, Gulp v3.9.1

I have this task in my Gulpfile.js:

```
var app = assemble();

app.helpers(helpers());

gulp.task('load', function(cb) {
  app.layouts(pathDir.layouts + '/*.hbs');
  app.pages(pathDir.pages + '/**/*.hbs');
  app.partials(pathDir.partials + '/**/*.hbs');
  app.data(pathDir.data + '/*.json');
  cb();
});

gulp.task('assemble', ['load'], function() {
  return app.toStream('pages')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(app.renderFile())
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(app.dest(pathDir.dev));
});
```

my test.json file looks like this:

```
{"title": "Das ist ein Test"}
```

My testpage.hbs looks like this:

```html
<div style="font-size:32px;">AAAA
  <span style="background-color:#f00;">{{test.title}}</span>
  BBB
</div>
```

In my rendered html i only get:

```html
<div style="font-size:32px;">AAAA<span style="background-color:#f00;"></span>BBB</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `namespace` option to the `app.data` method:

```
app.data(pathDir.data + '/*.json', {namespace: true});
```

It was mentioned in the changelog section that the `.data` method is using [base-data](https://github.com/node-base/base-data), but the api section hasn't been updated yet. The [namespacing option is described here](https://github.com/node-base/base-data#namespacing).

Comment: I still can´t see any output in my rendered html but i did a `console.log(app.cache.data)` and I see all of the json data in the Terminal, It just won´t show up in the rendered files.

Comment: I´m sorry to say that, but there was no error in my gulpfile. When I deleted some things in my default layout .hbs <head> section the data was suddenly rendered in my htmls. I'm trying to find out what in that <head> section caused it.

Comment: If there is another block or partial in the head, then the context level might have changed. You can try `{{@root.test.title}}` to try to get to the correct context level.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. It wasn´t the <head> section that caused it. I didn´t notice it before because I didn't just delete the content of the head section but also a prettify helper tag that was wrapped around my body tag. That was from my old grunt Project that used prettify. In my gulp project I use gulp-prettify and that doesn't have this helper and that caused the json data not to be rendered. But thanks a lot for your effort.